# "She lay inert in her bed"—is this sentence right?

Tags: grammaticality, adjectives

> She lay inert in her bed.

I found this sentence by Googling "inert". As "inert" is an adjective word, I think using "inert" to describe the verb "lay" is not correct. Is this sentence grammatically correct?

Comment: The sentence is not different from "She lay motionless in her bed" or "She sat motionless in her bed." It's okay as it is.

Comment: Your words inspire me. I guess the "inert" is to describe the state of "her", not the action of "lay", so  "was"  can replace the "lay": "She was inert in her bed" is OK, it won't make people confused.

Comment: Although the sentence is correct, it could mean that *she lay motionless* or that *she lay dead* as *inert* is ambiguous as to life or motion.

Comment: @RonaldSole - Except that "inert", when used to describe a person, commonly means still and not reacting to the environment.  Certainly a dead person is inert, but that is not what the word implies.

Comment: @Ronald Sole I think if using "dead",  it is not suitable to use "lay" to describe a alive person. Because dead person won't dead standing. So "She was dead in her bed" sound more comfortable .

Comment: @Jesse she could be sprawled dead in her bed, or sitting up dead in her bed, or curled up dead in her bed ... 'lay' certainly strikes a more composed state ... and perhaps she was laid out after being curled etc..  Just saying.. that the "lay" does convey a message

Comment: @HotLicks Implication granted! But might you accept beliefs surrounding the historical occupant of the Holy Sepulchre in Jerusalem as an excellent (if  most uncommon) example of the ambiguity.

Comment: Jesse, I don't like it either.  But the dictionary seems to back up this usage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The comments of @Yosef Baskin and @Hot Licks inspired me. But I want more explain about grammar. So I looked up grammar book and found some useful information.

In English, there is a import kind of sentence: **S + V + C**(subject + verb + complement). The **v** is adjective. Other than conveying the short action of **V**, the **C** in this kind of sentence is to describe the state or characteristic of **S** for a while or a long time. In this situation, the effects of **V** are to link **s** and the state or characteristic of **s**. So the **v** in this sentence is called *linking verb*.

Return to the sentence:"she lay inert in her bed". (Note well that the verb **lay** here is the past tense of **lie**). The **v** is "lay" to express the state of the girl lying, instead of the brief action of lying that we should use adverb to describe, for example, she lay quickly(or slowly, weakly and so on) in her bed. The theory is also apply to comments of @Tom22.

There are some other examples:

- Stay hungry.Stay foolish.
- He held silent for the whole day.
- The weather continued fine for several days

Comment: This answer appears to confuse the verb *lay/laid* with the verb *lie/lay/lain*. The verb *lay* is a transitive verb where something is deliberately placed; the past-tense *lay* comes from *lie* which is intransitive. The sentence "The *v* is *lay* to express the state of the girl laying..." is wrong: it should be *lying* there and the rest of that sentence needs re-working. I would have given this a +1 except for that.

Comment: The verb lay  in **she lay inert**  is just the past-tense of lie.

Comment: Yes, but that's not what your answer says, because it uses the word *laying*.